# Notation for multiplying with logical ($x_i > N$)

Tags: inequality, notation

For a vector $x_i$ and numeric values $\theta_j$ and $\beta_j$, I can write this vectorized calculation in R:

```
y = (x > theta1) * beta1 + (x > theta2) * beta2 + (x > theta3) * beta3
```

In programming, `x > theta1` evaluates to `TRUE` (1) and `FALSE` (0) and multiplication is straightforward. But how do I write this as a mathematical expression? This was my first hunch, but I'm not sure it would fare well:

$$
\begin{align}
y_i =& (x_i > \theta_1) \beta_1 + (x > \theta_2) \beta_2 + (x > \theta_3) \beta_3 \\
=& \sum_{j = 1}^{3} (x_i > \theta_j) \beta_j
\end{align}
$$

I would like to avoid a notation where the cumulative nature of the expression is less obvious and which quickly grows overly long. I have many more terms and comparators in actual equations.

$$
y_i = \begin{cases} 
  \beta_1 & \text{if } x_i > \theta_1 \\
  \beta_1 + \beta_2 & \text{if } x_i > \theta_2 \\
  \beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 & \text{if } x_i > \theta_3 \\
\end{cases}
$$

$x_i$ and $\theta_j$ are monotonically increasing.

Comment: Are we to take it that the sequence $\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots$ is increasing?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley, yes, and so too for $x_i$. I've updated the question with that clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an *indicator function*, which has value 1 for true expressions and value 0 for false expressions.  Conventionally it is denoted by putting the logical expression in *square brackets* (i.e '[]').

If you are writing this up for more than your own edification, I strongly recommend that you explicitly describe this notation up front so people don't get confused wondering why you are using 'mixed' grouping symbols.

Comment: Thank you! This is also called Iverson brackets. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: See: Donald E. Knuth, "Two Notes on Notation", *Amer. Math. Monthly* **99**, No. 5 (May, 1992), pp.403-422; and/or Ronald L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth and Oren Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics* (2nd ed. 1994), p.24f. From Knuth: "I hope that within five years everybody will be able to use these notations in published papers without needing to explain what they mean."

Answer (score 1):

Convenient though it undoubtedly is, I don't know if the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) notation is widely enough accepted to be used in a paper without an explanation or a reference, e.g. one of the references in the Wikipedia article just cited, including those I gave in a comment on the other answer.

(Perhaps one of the professional mathematicians who post here could comment authoritatively on that point?)

In any case, I feel that because the sequence $\theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots$ is increasing (incidentally, I don't think it is relevant that the sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ is increasing), which results in the special form of the sums for the $y_i$ as shown at the end of the question, it would be clearer (although less snappy) to write something along these general lines (vary according to taste):
\begin{gather*}
N_x = \max\{j : \theta_j < x\}, \\
s(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{N_x}\beta_j, \\
y_i = s(x_i).
\end{gather*}